# I want my app to not show articles or give them low priority to those that have already been seen

Tags: react-native

I have a basic article app like inshorts i am storing all the articles in database which i fetch on the opening and display them in card format.Now I want to implement that when a card id viewed it should get low priority and render at the end next time the app is opened on that mobile.

I have no clue how to implement this.

### This is how i am currently rendering it

```
  renderArtciles=()=>{
    let len=this.state.dataSource.length;
    return this.state.dataSource.map((item,i)=>{
      this.state.id=item._id;
      this.state.priority=item.priority;
      this.state.views=item.views;
        if (i == this.state.currentIndex-1)
        {
          return(
            <Animated.View key={item._id} {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers} style={this.state.swiped_pan.getLayout()}>
              < View  style={{  flex: 1,position:'absolute',height:height,width:width,backgroundColor:'white'}}>

                < View style={styles.Imagebody}>
                  <Image source={{ uri:item.img.data }} style={styles.image} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.inner}>
                  <Text>{item.body} i==={i}{this.state.currentIndex} </Text>
                </View>

              </View>
          </Animated.View>

        )
        }
        else if (i < this.state.currentIndex)
        {
          return null
        }
         if (i == this.state.currentIndex)
        {
          return(
            <Animated.View key={item._id} {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers} style={this.state.pan.getLayout()}>
              < View  style={{  flex: 1,position:'absolute',height:height,width:width,backgroundColor:'white'}}>

                < View style={styles.Imagebody}>
                  <Image source={{ uri:item.img.data }} style={styles.image} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.inner}>
                  <Text>{item.body} i==={i}{this.state.currentIndex} </Text>
                </View>

              </View>
          </Animated.View>

        )
      }
      else{
        return(
          <Animated.View key={item._id} >
            < View  style={{  flex: 1,position:'absolute',height:height,width:width,backgroundColor:'white'}}>

              < View style={styles.Imagebody}>
                <Image source={{ uri:item.img.data }} style={styles.image} />
              </View>

              <View style={styles.inner}>
                <Text>{item.body} i==={i}{this.state.currentIndex} ﻿</Text>
              </View>

            </View>
        </Animated.View>

      )


      }

    }
  ).reverse()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) to store which items have been viewed (and how many times) in a JSON object which you can increment every time an item is viewed, and then retrieve again when the app is opened (and store in some state variable). You can then work out your ordering/priority logic based on the number of views.

To store the items you would do something like this:

```
 _storeData = async () => {
  try {
    var itemsJson = {items: [
        {item_id: 'foo', view_count: 10},
        {item_id: 'bar', view_count: 5}
    ]}

    await AsyncStorage.setItem('ItemViews', JSON.stringify(itemsJson));
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

And to retrieve the items on app open you would do something like this:

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ItemViews');

    // Rest of your code
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,this did the job.I just had another question,how am i supposed to sort the map function according to the views in async storage when i am mapping using another JSON variable.The only way i know to sort a map is  ``` .sort(a,b)=>a.var>b.var)```